# Elasticsearch- Filtering out unique docs based on a field value and prioritizing on basis of another field value

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a dataset of stocks in Elasticsearch, in which there can be cases where one stock can be listed on multiple exchanges. Key to identify unique stock is ISIN.
So, I have few ISINs which can be present in 2 docs one with Exch: "NSE", one with Exch: "BSE".
How can I filter out my query result set such that in case of multiple records of same ISIN, Exch: "NSE" gets prioritized and Exch: "BSE" doesn't come up in result.

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 6329,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stkindex",
        "_id": "2277NSEE",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "Exch": "NSE",
          "Sym": "MRF",
          "Isin": "INE883A01011"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stkindex",
        "_id": "500290BSEE",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "Exch": "BSE",
          "Isin": "INE883A01011",
          "Sym": "MRF"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stkindex",
        "_id": "517174BSEE",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "Exch": "BSE",
          "Isin": "INE671A01010",
          "Sym": "HONAUT"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you see the above query result, you can see the stock MRF comes 2 times, one with Exch NSE and one with BSE. What I want here is MRF should come only once which has Exch as "NSE".

Tried aggregations but it doesn't gave me expected results.

Answer (score 0):

### Collapse API

simply take a look at [collapse API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html).

You just need to collapse the result based on `ISIN` and use the sort section to prioritize the `Exch` either `desc` or `asc` based on your needs. (here `NSE` is greater than `BSE`, so `desc` should work for you)